# TYPO3 Fluid dynamic variable part in inline if condition

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to check for existence of configuration array in settings and, if present, pass it as argument to a partial. If it doesn't exist, pass default configuration to that partial.

My problem is, that I'm stuck at if-condition, where the check needs to be performed (then-else are simplified below):

```
{f:if(condition: settings.media.responsive{f:count(subject: records)}, then: 'true', else: 'false')}
```

Such a code is not parsed by Fluid and is simply output as is on the page.
However without dynamic part it works perfectly:

```
{f:if(condition: settings.media.responsive1, then: 'true', else: 'false')}
```

Outputs `true`.

I've tried all possible combinations: with single-quotes and/or curly brackets around the whole condition, as well as same inside of `f:count(subject)`, but didn't find a way to make it work.

Additionaly tried `v:variable.get` from VHS extension, but also without success:

```
{f:if(condition: {v:variable.get(name: 'settings.media.responsive{f:count(subject: records)}')}, then: 'true', else: 'false')}
```

The code above always results in `true`.

**Important** note: `settings.media.responsive[number]` contains array of settings, so can't be casted to string by surrounding it with single-quotes in `condition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Fluid engine library:

```
{records -> f:variable(name: 'count')}
{f:if(condition: '{f:count(subject: \'{settings.media.responsive{count}}\')}', then: 'true', else: 'false')}
```

Or if you want VHS:

```
{f:if(condition: '{v:variable.get(name: \'settings.media.responsive{f:count(subject: records)}\') -> f:count()}', then: 'true', else: 'false')}
```

Comment: The problem is, that I can't cast  `settings.media.responsive[number]` to sring, because it contains an array of settings. And wrapping condition in single-quotes results in `#1476107295: PHP Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /path/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/EscapingNode.php line 44`

Comment: Example updated to reflect the new information that your dynamically named setting is itself an array. Condition now counts the array located in the dynamic variable reference and does `true` case if count is > 0. FYI, the example is null-safe so if the dynamic reference returns null, bad things won't happen (`else` case triggers).

Comment: Thank you, now the vhs-part works, but the pure Fluid-way brings me always `true`. However, the issue is resolved, so answer is accepted.